# What matplotlib object should I send/receive through class method?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, you can create figure, manage axes of this figure (subplot actually ?) but I do not understand why and how, at the end you do `plt.show()` to see the plot. Why this is not a method of the `fig` or `ax` object ? How does the module (plt) know what to plot ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = np.random.randn(2, 100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, "ro")
plt.show()
```

I ask this question because now, suppose you have a class with a method in order to make a plot of the data contained in the object. My question is what object I am suppose to return ? Axes, Figure or plt ? Is one of the followings method the right way to do that :

```
def get_plot(self):
    """ return plt """
    plt.plot(self.data.x, self.data.y)
    return plt

def get_plot(self):
    """ return fig """
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(self.data.x, self.data.y)
    return fig

def get_plot(self):
    """ return ax """
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(self.data.x, self.data.y)
    return ax
```

The last one is, maybe, the clearest because you see on each line the object on which you are working. But if I get a Figure or Axes object. How can I easily plot it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plt.show`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) will show all figures that have been created. So there's no need to for `pyplot` to "know" which one, since all will be displayed. From the docs:

> Display a figure. When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display
>   all figures and return to the ipython prompt.
>
> In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until the
>   figures have been closed

I would personally return the `fig` or `ax`, since then you can perform other functions on that object (e.g. `ax.set_xlim`, or `fig.savefig()` etc.). There's no need to return `plt`, since that is the `pyplot` module that you have already imported.